# Debug in MonoDevelop Flatpak

Tags: debugging, mono, debian, flatpak

just installed MonoDevelop flatpak in Debian

i run it with

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
```

The problem is that im getting a error when debugging a simple console project:

```
 "Cannot execute "/home/unknow/Projects/test/test/bin/Debug/test.exe"
```

What can i do to open the external console?

I found nothing in google

Comment: the flatpack of monodevelop is experimental, please report bugs about it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/